# spring boot jsp & executable jar throws /error

Tags: maven, jsp, tomcat, spring-boot

I am trying to excute my SpringBoot webapp jar which throws page not found error.
but it will work correctly when running on Spring-Too-Suite.

my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
    public class WudiDataApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(WudiDataApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

application.propertie file like below

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/ 

spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

server.port=8080
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.wudidata</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>newWudiData</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
     </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>


        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

....update....

i already created the configuration class as given below, but still show the same error..

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 @EnableWebMvc
 public class DbConfig { 
.......}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually we cant create jar with jsp in spring boot. try to create war and it has some specific folder structure required

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a configuration classe to enable web mvc

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig {

}
```

Comment: i already created the configuration  class as given below, but still show the same error..
(@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc)
public class DbConfig {
}